# jQuery Function restart or loop

Tags: jquery, function, loops, restart

All i would like to do is that this function ones ends just restart or make a loop. please some help, thx. =)

this is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#text').hide();
    $('#text').delay(600).fadeIn(1500).delay(9000).fadeOut(2000);
    $('#text2').hide();
    $('#text2').delay(13500).fadeIn(1500).delay(9000).fadeOut(2000);
    $('#text3').hide();
    $('#text3').delay(26500).fadeIn(1500).delay(9000).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Comment: Why are you using document ready handler twice

Comment: i got the code from some where else, but im also new in all this, basically learning from the masters =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` accept a callback function as the second argument which is executed after the animation finishes.  You can take advantage of this function by placing the dynamic parts of your transition into an array.  In my code, I have created a function which starts the transitions and then calls itself recursively via a callback function.  With each recursion the next index is passed as an argument, which is used to retrieve the transition information from the array.

```
$(function() {
    $('#text, #text2, #text3').hide();
    var transitions = [
        {id: 'text', delay: 600},
        {id: 'text2', delay: 13500},
        {id: 'text3', delay: 26500}
    ];

    function perform(i){
        $('#' + transitions[i].id).delay(transitions[i].delay).fadeIn(1500).delay(9000).fadeOut(2000, function(){
             perform(++i % transitions.length);
        });     
    }
    perform(0);                          
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/z5Wcd/

Comment: Kevin, thank you so much for your help, this really resolve my problem. its great. thank you again, today i learn something new.

Comment: This is nicely done, above all the `%` part for avoiding the `for` loop. But check my `.promise()` part out for the future. @Haroldo

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
  function loop() {
   $('#text').hide();
   $('#text').delay(600).fadeIn(1500).delay(9000).fadeOut(2000);
   $('#text2').hide();
   $('#text2').delay(13500).fadeIn(1500).delay(9000).fadeOut(2000);
   $('#text3').hide();
   $('#text3').delay(26500).fadeIn(1500).delay(9000).fadeOut(2000);
   $('classOrTagThatEveryElementHas').promise().done(loop);
  }
  loop();
});
```

**Documentation:** http://api.jquery.com/promise/

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/RW22m/